# Fill array with values without loop in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

Is there any method (that doesn't use loop or recursion) to create and fill an array with values?

To be precise, I want to have an effect of

```
$t = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $t[] = "val";
}
```

But simpler.

Comment: I know this question is kinda old, but how to fill the array with range of int instead of string ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

use [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

```
$t = array_fill(0, $n, 'val');
```

Comment: Darn you beat me to it ;P
For any interested, though, it turns out array_fill is up to 4x faster than the for loop version

Comment: This creates a filled array, it doesn't fill an array, two *very different things*.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use

```
$array = array_pad(array(), $n, "val");
```

to get the desired effect.

See [array_pad()](http://php.net/array_pad) on php.net

Answer (score 5):

```
$a = array('key1'=>'some value', 'KEY_20'=>0,'anotherKey'=>0xC0DEBABE);
```

/* we need to nullify whole array with keep safe keys*/

```
$a = array_fill_keys(array_keys($a),NULL);

var_export($a);

/*result:

array(
     'key1'=>NULL, 
     'KEY_20'=>NULL,
     'anotherKey'=>NULL
);
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$keys = array('foo', 5, 10, 'bar');
$a = array_fill_keys($keys, 'banana');
print_r($a);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => banana
    [5] => banana
    [10] => banana
    [bar] => banana
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean. There are functions to fill arrays, but they will all use loops behind the scenes. Assuming you are just looking to avoid loops in *your* code, you could use [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

```
// Syntax: array_fill(start index, number of values; the value to fill in);
$t = array_fill(0, $n, 'val');
```

I.e.

```
<?php
    $t = array_fill(0, 10, 'val');
    print_r($t);
?>
```

Will give:

```
Array (
    [0] => val
    [1] => val
    [2] => val
    [3] => val 
    [4] => val 
    [5] => val 
    [6] => val 
    [7] => val 
    [8] => val 
    [9] => val 
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$a = array(); 
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
$a[] = "value";
```

you get the idea

Comment: How is that simpler for him? Itsthe same thing with more code and its harderto keep track of how many items you are creating. 
EDIT:just realised you indeed fulfill his demand ofno loops but really.

Comment: Because that's the only way to fill an array without a loop. Any other method is using a loop behind the scenes regardless.

Comment: @Iznogood yes really, he asked i answered, dont burn the messenger.  :-)