# php array from 1 to 200 any fast way?

Tags: php, arrays, range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fill array with values without loop in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506773/fill-array-with-values-without-loop-in-php)

I have bought an php contact form and I am trying to make a validator.
So instead of typing like this:

```
$amount->addValidator('identical', array( 
'token' => array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35')
```

));

Is there any fast way to make it as an range from 1 to 200 as valid answers? I have typed 35 and got tired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$array = range(1, 200);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 1):

you can use range function to generate array which contains 1 to 200 elements

```
$arr = range(1,200);
```